# What is the best tutorial to convert a substrate-based standalone chain to a parachain?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, parachain

What is the best tutorial to convert a substrate-based standalone chain to a parachain?

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of tutorials on https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/

Here is one to convert

https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the tutorials mentioned by Sam, [this workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfwg2aMz66I&list=PLp0_ueXY_enX6S5sogeo7GHD1BXTLj5Xr) is very thorough as it explains all the steps of taking your solochain to a parachain as well as building the front-end for it. It even ends with demoing the entire application.

Skip to [this part](https://youtu.be/sfwg2aMz66I?list=PLp0_ueXY_enX6S5sogeo7GHD1BXTLj5Xr&t=2751) to get an overview of the steps you'll need to take to convert your solo-chain to a parachain connected to a live relay chain.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out this presentation which has Centrifuge's solochain to parachain migration as a case study
(Sub0 Online: Storage Migration - Standalone chain to Parachain
):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIgvyRFs-N4

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the docs on how to convert a silo chain to a parachain: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/

Note that you must perform state *migrations* on your new parachain_starting from genesis_ to populate the desired state on the parachain. You cannot simply "flip a switch" on a running chain to become a parachain.
https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/runtime-upgrade/

It is likely you need to evaluate your benchmarking closely and fit into the *much more strick and limited* weight requirements for parachain operation, compared to solo chain operation as well. You may need to redactor or when prune functionality based on those investigations.
https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/weights/add-benchmarks/