# Steps to connect chain to rococo test

Tags: substrate-node-template, rococo, substrate-node

I have chain built using `substrate-node-template`. Now what are the steps to connect my chain to Rococo test network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have build a chain using the `substrate-node-template` you have a solo chain, you have to integrate [Cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus) to convert your Substrate FRAME runtime into a Parachain runtime.

There is a tutorial on the Substrate docs about it: [Convert a solo chain](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/parachains/convert-a-solo-chain/), personally is not my favourite tutorial there, is worth reading to understand the theory but not very practical.

If you are in a early stage I suggest you to start with the [Substrate Cumulus Parachain Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template).

> This project is originally a fork of the Substrate Node Template
> modified to include dependencies required for registering this node as
> a parathread or parachain to a relay chain.

Or you can use it as a reference to check what you need to add into your chain, another good resource is the [Cumulus Overview](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/docs/overview.md).

The community shared more resources before in this StackExchange question: [What is the best tutorial to convert a substrate-based standalone chain to a parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-the-best-tutorial-to-convert-a-substrate-based-standalone-chain-to-a-par)

**Deploy on Rococo**

Once you have your parachain, there is a tutorial in the Substrate Docs that demonstrates how you can deploy a parachain on the Rococo test network: [Acquire a testnet slot](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/).

To update some things, you can get ROC tokens using the new [Polkadot Faucet](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-testnet-faucet/) instead of the element channel.

And when you have everything ready open a request [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml) to get your slot on the Rococo chain.

Comment: Ben I don't have parachain yet, I have just chain built using `substrate-node-template`. How to convert into parachain?

Comment: Edited my answer! Sorry I missed that part

Comment: instead of using `substrate-node-template` as a step to develop chain in substrate we can directly start from `substrate-parachain-template` also in next time? then we don't have to follow all this steps to convert solo chain to parachain yes? @Alex

Comment: If the goal is to become a parachain defintely, yes